# Calculate Sin Y given X (with offset)

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

I have a function ([from here](https://riptutorial.com/javascript/example/10173/periodic-functions-using-math-sin)) that calculates the coordinate Y when given X

```
function calculateSinYGivenX(time, frequency = 1, amplitude = 1, phase = 0, offset = 0) {
  return Math.sin((time * frequency * (Math.PI * 2)) + (phase * (Math.PI * 2))) * amplitude + offset; 
}
```

So far my tests pass as expected

```
expect(calculateSinYGivenX(time = 0, frequency = 1, amplitude = 1, phase = 0, offset = 0)).toEqual(0);
expect(calculateSinYGivenX(time = 0.25, frequency = 1, amplitude = 1, phase = 0, offset = 0)).toEqual(1);
expect(calculateSinYGivenX(time = 0.5, frequency = 1, amplitude = 1, phase = 0, offset = 0)).toBeCloseTo(0);
expect(calculateSinYGivenX(time = 0.75, frequency = 1, amplitude = 1, phase = 0, offset = 0)).toEqual(-1);
expect(calculateSinYGivenX(time = 1, frequency = 1, amplitude = 1, phase = 0, offset = 0)).toBeCloseTo(0);
```

To illustrate:

[image]

When I try to shift the wave to the right (`phase = 0.5`), they fail

```
expect(calculateSinYGivenX(time = 0, frequency = 1, amplitude = 1, phase = 0.5, offset = 0)).toEqual(-1);
expect(calculateSinYGivenX(time = 0, frequency = 1, amplitude = 1, phase = 1, offset = 0)).toEqual(0);
expect(calculateSinYGivenX(time = 0, frequency = 1, amplitude = 1, phase = 1.5, offset = 0)).toEqual(1);


Expected -1.2246467991473532e-16 to equal -1
Expected 2.4492935982947064e-16 to equal 0
Expected -3.6739403974420594e-16 to equal 1
```

To illustrate:

[image]

I'm unfortunately not good enough at maths to figure out where I'm going wrong. I've used online sources to get to this point, but I can't seem to get it to work as expected.

Comment: According to a [possible source](https://riptutorial.com/javascript/example/10173/periodic-functions-using-math-sin) of your javascript function, `Offset: moves the whole wave up or down.`.  Read about the phase parameter i think that’s what you’re after.

Comment: You are right, I was confusing offset and phase shift. I corrected this (and in my question), but I am still getting unexpected results... I'm going to try and plot it. Maybe if I can see it, I can figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After reading and testing few things, phase is just the starting time, so it can be understood as 'time offset'.
As a result, the composition of `time + phase` will always give the same result (for fixed frequency, amplitude and offset)

For example :

```
console.log(calculateSinYGivenX(time = 0.25, frequency = 1, amplitude = 1, phase = 1.26, offset = 0));
console.log(calculateSinYGivenX(time = 1.26, frequency = 1, amplitude = 1, phase = 0.25, offset = 0));
console.log(calculateSinYGivenX(time = 1.50, frequency = 1, amplitude = 1, phase = 0.01, offset = 0));
=> 
-0.06279051952931265
-0.06279051952931265
-0.06279051952931265
```

So things are working as expected for the phase variable.

Be careful of floating point variable handle in JS, you used the `toBeCloseTo(x)` function, so I suggest you to use it for your comparisons.